# Replace Images by their alt-text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, text, replace

I found out so far how to replace element by another element on a html-page. But my function is working in a strange way. First it replaces first and third image. If i invoke it again, it replaces only the second image. Pressing button again makes finally the last fourth image replace. Somebody any ideas about that? Here's the source: http://pastie.org/5502630
And here you can see how it works: http://clubnights.square7.ch/webtech/a2.html

Comment: Has anybody an idea, how to make pictures show up again on second click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each pass through the `for` loop, you remove the first image from the `images[]` array. This changes both the array contents and the array length set as the conditional in your loop.

For example, your first loop through removes `images[0]`, ausdruck_1.gif -- but now images.length equals 3, not 4, and the contents of the array are now:

```
images[0]=ausdruck_2.gif
images[1]=ausdruck_3.gif
images[2]=ausdurck_4.gif
```

Your second pass through the loop removes `images[1]` -- now ausdruck_3.gif -- and further changes the length of the images array to 2, so the next increment of i to 2 causes the loop to exit.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeoravec/VDqGF/) showing a possible solution of changing your for statement to:

`for(i = images.length-1; i >=0; i--)`

and looping through the images in reverse order.

Comment: Another similar solution: use a while loop that takes the last image in the list each time. http://jsfiddle.net/VDqGF/3/

Comment: @Joe Oravec
What can you say about this solution? http://jsfiddle.net/VDqGF/5/
I just removed the increment statement

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the list of images as you're iterating through it. So when you try to access the images array it's not what you think it is! Below is a possible workaround..

```
    function Convert()
    {
            images = window.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            var num_images = images.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < num_images; i++)
            {
                    var image = images[0];
                    textReplacement = document.createTextNode(image.getAttribute('alt'));
                    image.parentNode.replaceChild(textReplacement, image);
            }
    }
```